# electron affinities of Be and Ca

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electron-affinity

I have found in the textbook that Be has negative electron affinity while Ca has positive why? how can I compare the electron affinity values of these two.?

Comment: You can compare by comparing electronegativities of each of them. In general electron affinity is directly proportional to electro negativity.

Comment: explain a bit..